# Centre message in AlertDialog box

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom title for my AlertDialog box. But I have not been able to centre the message. It always comes left aligned.

```
    TextView vehicle_no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_no);
    String ScoreTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.AlertTitle);

    AlertDialog.Builder alrtbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Context mContext = alrtbuilder.getContext();
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_dialog, null);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTextView.setText(ScoreTitle);
```

The AlertDialog box has a positive and a negative button

```
    alrtbuilder.setCustomTitle(mView);
    alrtbuilder.setMessage(vehicle_no.getText().toString().toUpperCase()+" "+"?")
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    insert_timecard();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).show;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to `TextView` with id `R.id.title_text` in your layout `R.layout.simple_dialog`.

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

To center default message `TextView` you have to get the `TextView` from dialog after `show()`.

```
 alertDialog.show();
            TextView messageView = (TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I do not know if its a good approach but you can also set the  custom view to whole dialog then things can be handled easily.

Comment: I don't want to centre the title_text. I want to centre the setMessage part  setMessage(vehicle_no.getText())

Answer (score 1):

Add:

> mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
>
> ```
> TextView vehicle_no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_no);
> String ScoreTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.AlertTitle);
>
> AlertDialog.Builder alrtbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
> Context mContext = alrtbuilder.getContext();
> LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
> View mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_dialog, null);
> TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
> mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
> mTextView.setText(ScoreTitle);
> ```

This should resolve:

Answer (score 1):

how about adding this?

```
TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```